# Python Socket Application Errno 11. Issue with receive function

Tags: python, sockets

I have written a socket chat program in python but I'm encountering an issue while communicating with the server. The full code is in the link below (client and server). The code is too long to write here:

https://github.com/Hunter-Zolomon/SafeChat/tree/experimental

While testing the program, running the server on my machine and connecting locally, both the file transfer (Large Files) and chat work as they should. However, when i run the server code on my remote machine on another network, files larger than a couple of KBs somehow trigger the `recv()` function prematurely which returns the boolean value of `False`, thus when the condition - `while not (decrypted_message["data"][:8] == 'SFTP END'.encode('utf-8'))` - tries to check the data, the program throws an exception and exits. Consequently, the client raises an Errno 11 because no connection exists. Weirdly, small files transfers work with no problems and the chat functionality also works. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm new so if my question has issues, I'm happy to edit it with the correct format.

Edit: The issue was resolved using a `select.select([], [socket], [])` for the client upload as well as the `recv_exact()` function suggested by tdelaney with an added `errno` exception handle for the client download.

Comment: After a quick search for `recv` I saw `message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH);` and `client_socket.recv(message_length)`. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. There is no guarantee that a single recv will get exactly the size you ask for. The only guarantee is that you'll get at least 1 byte.

Comment: Oh, and lose all of those semicolons at the end. Its only allowed to keep C programmers from hyperventilating.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream protocol and there is no guarantee that a `recv` will receive exactly the data from a single `send` or that it will be exactly the count you ask for. For a blocking socket, `recv(somelen)` will receive at least 1 byte, and at most `somelen` bytes. If you want to receive an exact amount of data, write an intermediate function to help.

```
def recv_excact(sockobj, size):
    buflist = []
    while size:
        buf = sockobj.recv(size)
        if not buf:
            return False
        buflist.append(buf)
        size -= len(buf)
    return  b"".join(buflist)
```

Comment: The program is designed with headers on each message in order to eliminate the need for fixed sized recv(). Why do I need this intermediary function? Sorry I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Lets say I call `recv(64)`. I can get anywhere from 1 to 64 bytes. If I really need all 64 then I need to keep calling `recv` until I get it. You say you've eliminated the need for fixed sized recv, but you do `client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)` which is a fixed size recv. You then do `client_socket.recv(message_length)`, another fixed size recv. Each of those may have returned only 1 byte. (I'm assuming `client_socket` is a `socket` object... didn't track that back in your code).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I implemented your intermediary code to solidify the receive function, however, the problem still persists when i run the server code on a remote machine. From what i can tell, `buf = sockobj.recv(size)` returns an empty byte for some reason just like last time. Perhaps the server is closing the connection to prevent from attacks when there is a continuous flow of large data chunks. This could explain why the `recv()` function is returning empty.

Comment: Empty means the socket has been shutdown by the remote. I don't know your protocol well enough, but if simply closing a socket is how you say goodbye, you'd expect that empty recv. Also, `sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` before close is the proper way to do a graceful termination (shutting down the write side send as FIN after all data is sent).  I also noticed an  `except:` without a log message - could be there. Just guesses!

Comment: Well I haven't written a graceful shutdown procedure yet, because I have been focusing on getting this bug fixed. For now, both the server and client understand that a closed socket means one of the parties has disconnected. As I mentioned in my question, when the `recv()` returns empty, the wrapper function returns False. When the program proceeds to check the data it expected to receive from the wrapper function, it is unable to slice a boolean value and so crashes due to an exception. The client then crashes because the server unexpectedly closed. I dont understand why `recv()` is empty.

Comment: After further experimentation, i seem to have narrowed the scope of the problem. I tried stepping over the client side code while sending a large file and surprisingly, it seems to go through. This leads me to believe that my `send_message()` function is sending data too quickly. This throws an Errno 11 exception on `send()` which in turn returns an empty byte on `recv()` on the server side. I'm not completely sure about this but could this be an issue? If so how can i mitigate this problem?

Comment: @HunterZolomon - You are using non-blocking sockets so that explanation makes sense. Errno 11 says that the socket send buffer is full and you'll need to wait until `select` says that its writable again (that's the second list passed to `select`). Your select poll loop should handle both sends and receives. This can be tricky because you don't want to do a blocking file read in the select loop as it would slow everyone down. On linux you can make file reads nonblocking and handle them in the same select loop. On windows you can't because file system handles aren't recognized by `select`.

Comment: Perhaps a background thread could prestage file read buffers. Its going to be a bit tricky!

Comment: I have been threading my code because people weren't able to use the program on windows, so I have to go the threaded route. How would I write the tricky bit you suggested? Perhaps you could aid me in chat?

Comment: I temporarily wrote a blocking write on the uploader's side to test if it would solve the issue of uploading too quickly. The user can now upload without problems, however, the receiver is now receiving data too quickly (`DownloadFile()` function) and I have not been able to come up with a way to slow it down through I/O. I debugged the `DownloadFile()` function with thread sleeping to confirm that the issue was the receiving speed, and it was indeed the issue.

Comment: So I would appreciate it if you could propose a solution to slow down the receive for Download, and ideally, optimize the whole process(Upload/Download) without slowing everyone down, which the current (shoddy) architecture does. I have updated the code on Github (experimental branch) with the aforementioned changes.